# Excel Formula for returning cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i'm looking for an excel formula that will return every 4th cell.
For example if i have in column A the following:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9

I'm looking for a formula that will return every second cell, i would like my B column to show me

- 1
- 3
- 5
- 7
- 9...

i tried using Offset with no success.
Thank you
Assaf

Comment: Your question asks for every 4th cell, but your data shows every 2nd cell after the first

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,2*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+1,1)
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: since it is a 1D array you are indexing, do you need that last ",1"?

Comment: I think its the same habit of mine with offset where I finish with ,1,1 when I just want a single cell instead of leaving it blank.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I highly recommend Gary's approach as it is a non-volatile solution.  I will be providing an offset solution to match your initial thought process.  However I do not recommend using it if you have a lot of offset or other volatile functions in your workbook as they can cause things to slow down significantly after a certain number of them.  Volatile formulas recalculate every time something on the worksheet changes, where a non volatile functions only recalculates when the ranges it refers to change.

```
=OFFSET(A1,2*(ROW(A1)-1)+1,0,1,1)
```

Place that where you want your data to start and copy down as far as required.